# A dimension problem in commutative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring ($A$ has an identity element), $\mathcal{I}$ is a non-zero ideal of $A$. If $\mathcal{I}$ is a free $A$-module, then we can suppose $\mathit e_{1}, \mathit e_{2},\dots,\mathit e_{n}$ be a basis of $\mathcal{I}$ and let $\mathcal{M}$ be a maximal ideal of $A$ containing $\mathcal{I}$. Now, we know that $\mathcal{I/MI}$ is a free $A/\mathcal{M}$-module (where $\mathcal{MI}$ means the submodule of $\mathcal{I}$ formed by all linear combinations of elements of $\mathcal{I}$ with coefficients in $\mathcal{M}$). Because $A/\mathcal{M}$ is a field, $\mathcal{I/MI}$ is a vector space. My question is:

**How much is the dimension of the vector space $\mathcal{I/MI}$ ?**

I guess it is 1, but I couldn't prove it.

One may say that  $\overline{ e } _1, \overline{ e } _2, \dots, \overline{ e } _n$ in $\mathcal{I/MI}$ is a basis, but I think they are the same, i.e. $\overline{ e } _1=\overline{ e } _2=\cdots=\overline{ e } _n$. Because we have a conclusion says: **if this $\mathcal{I}$ is free, then it is principal**. Then $\mathcal{I}$ has only one generator $x$, and $x$ is a basis of $\mathcal{I}$. We can get $\overline{ x }$ is a basis of  $\mathcal{I/MI}$, and I guess $\dim(\mathcal{I/MI})=1$. But I couldn't prove my question without the conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a non-zero ideal $I$ is a free module, then it has rank one, being generated by a non-zerodivisor. Consequently $\dim_{A/\mathfrak m} I/\mathfrak mI=1$. (In fact, $\dim I/\mathfrak mI$ equals the minimal number of generators of $I$ when $A$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$.)